# Eclim installation freeze on specifying vimfiles

Tags: eclim

I used the jar I downloaded from [eclim site](http://eclim.org/install.html#download). But my Eclim's installation won't progress because it is stuck in this dialog.

[image]

NOTE:I have all the latest requirements required by the installer.

Answer (score 0):

I uninstall my java8 and installation succeeded. I'm not sure if it's coincidence but it solve my problem.